# Why is my object always created facing the viewport camera?

Tags: 3d-view, camera

Whenever I add an object to the scene, it's always facing my viewport camera. Is there a way to set it back to always zero out the rotation in the world space?

If I create a cube, it's facing me instead of having 0 rotation on three axes. Anyone knows why this is and how to set it back?

[image]

Comment: if the answer has helped, pls accept the answer

Answer (score 4):

Once you created an object, expand the panel in the lower-left corner of your screen and set `Align` to `World`.

[image]

For Blender to remember this setting, do the following:
`Blender Preferences` > `Editing` > `Objects` > `New Objects` > `Align To` set to `World`
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: if the answer helped and it's the one you needed, please, accept it.